# df.tail() in pyspark alternatives?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to compare the data of a large file through PySpark. I've used `head()` and `tail()` statements for this, but they both return the same data and that's not right ...

What other alternative to view these two parts of the data file is there?

Comment: please show your code and sample data. `df.head(1)` and `df.tail(1)` works perfectly fine with me

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your data frame is `df` you can use:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df = df.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())
df.orderBy(desc("index")).drop("index").show(5)
```

[source](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/extract-top-n-rows-in-pyspark-first-n-rows/)